# How to notify user the file they submitted is too large in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resume

I essentially want to tell the user if they submit a file too large.  Right now, it redirects to an error page.  How do I get a basic popup or just write to the screen saying the file is too large if they submit a large file.  ASP.NET MVC5 has a set maxlength so I can't define the size limit.  Please help, have been trying for a while now with no results. Thanks

```
VIEW, CSHTML FILE
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

<div id="progressbar">
<div id="progressbar" class="all-rounded" style="width: 20%"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">

<h2>Job Application Management System</h2>
<p class="lead2"> Welcome @((string)(ViewData["FullName"])), Please upload your resume here. Thank you!</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =     "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <label> &nbsp; </label> <input type="file" class="btn btn-default"   name="File" id="File" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="upload" value="Upload" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    if (TempData["notice"] != null)
    {
        <p>@TempData["notice"]</p>
        <p><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Accomplishments")';return false;">Continue To Accomplishments</button></p>
    }
}
```

```
public class HomeController : ApplicationController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GET: /Home/Register
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>View of index</returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GET: /Home/Upload
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>View of upload</returns>
    public ActionResult Upload(int? jobId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// POST: /Home/Upload
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resume">Resume</param>
    /// <param name="command">string</param>
    /// <returns>Resume added and continue</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Upload(Resume resume, string command)
    {
        if (command == "Next")
        {
            RedirectToAction("Create", "Accomplishments");
        }
        try
        {
            if (resume.File.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(resume.File.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Resumes"), fileName);
                resume.File.SaveAs(path);
            }
            TempData["notice"] = "Resume Added:  "+ resume.File.FileName;
            return View(resume);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Upload Error";
            return View("Upload");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contact page (unused)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>View of contact</returns>
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This is something that is better to be handled from the client-side, because whatever the solution you wanna have on the server, will require the file to be fully uploaded before you can check the file size, or at least send an ajax call with the detected file size, which is better to be fully handled on the client.

My suggested solution is to use the following jquery snippet which I usually use when in need of a similar check.

```
$(function () {
    $('#fuPicture').bind('change', function () {
          // check if the file is larger than 600kb
          if (this.files[0].size > 819200) {                                
              alert("file is larger than 600kb, please choose a smaller one.")              
          } 
        else {
                // passed.                      
             }
     });
})
```

The previous code is handling the (change) event of the fileupload control and checks if the selected file size is larger than a desired size (600kb), then it alerts the user that the selected file is larger than the allowed one.

note that "**fuPicture**" is the ID of your fileupload control. and the returned size from this check (`this.files[0].size`) is in bytes, so you will need to convert your desired size to bytes first.

Comment: do you know where I would embed this code in my asp.net mvc project? Would it be in the view where I submit my resume?

Comment: what would my ID for fileupload control be? It should be shown in code above, right?

Comment: 1- yes this code has to be placed inside your view file "cshtml".
2- yes, must be inside a javascript tag
3- the ID is for the fileupload control inside your view file.

Comment: I have edited and added my cshtml file above. Do you know where that javascript would be embedded?

Comment: the file should be like the follownig one: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dcce3e7178fb17a1d021

Comment: do you see what fuPicture would be replaced with?

Comment: would the id be "upload"

Comment: If I implement your code and use upload as the id, I still get redirected to a page that says "Maximum request length exceeded". Just trying to get that pop up on page to notify them

Comment: you will need to handle the "submit" event via jquery, and force check the selected file size before continue to submit the page, if the check is failed, you will cancel the submit event and notify the user.

Comment: How do I make sure I am handling the "submit" even via jquery? Should I be inputting some code so that jquery is accessible?

Comment: With the code above, can you help me write out that javascript statement correctly? and please let me know if you think I need to add something to the top of my file so that jquery can be used.

Comment: please help if you can